# Flex: Tree component: keeping state when data provider updates

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

How would I go about keeping the state of a tree control? 
I'd like to keep the state of the tree when it's data provider gets updated, instead of it collapsing.

Comment: Are you setting an entirely new dataProvider during the update?  For example:

    myTree.dataProvider = myCollection;

Comment: yes, I am setting a new dataProvider, same basic structure just has more or less nodes

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this :

```
    var openItems:Object = tree.openItems;
    tree.dataProvider = myNewDataProvider;
    tree.openItems = openItems;
    tree.validateNow();
```

I'm not sure how well this will work if the new dataProvider is radically different from the old one, but it works when you're lazy loading tree nodes.

Comment: sounds great to me too, can't get the bastard to work though.
When you say it should work if the dataProvider is radically different what does that mean exactly? the updated provider I'm using will have new or deleted nodes

Comment: Actually, I've just tested it with some code that adds and removes nodes and it seems to work fine for me (there's presumably some code in the tree which checks whether the openItems exist in the tree and discards any that don't). In what way is it not working?

Comment: Well, using your snippet above my dataProvider updates, but returns the tree to a closed state. In debug mode I check the openItems and it does grab and reset them but the tree remains closed.

Comment: At this stage you might have to post some code. Are you actually updating the dataProvider rather than creating an entirely new one each time?

Comment: No I am not modifying the existing dp, I'm creating a new one and assigning it exactly like you've stated above

Comment: That would be your problem then. openItems contains references to specific instances and if those don't exist in your new version of the dataProvider it won't be able to open them. The code I've given works only if myNewDataProvider is the updated dataProvider, not an entirely new collection.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I got it working. The key is to invoke

```
*yourTreeInstance*.validateDisplayList();
```

after updating your tree's dataprovider. My code below:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        var treeDataProvider:XML;

        private function onTreeCreated(event:FlexEvent):void{

            // update value with new XML here;
            treeDataProvider = <node name="root">
                                   <node name="child 1">
                                       <node name = "grand child 1"/>
                                   </node>
                                </node>;

            myTree.openItems = treeDataProvider..node;
            myTree.validateDisplayList();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:Tree id="myTree" labelField="@name" dataProvider={treeDataProvider} 
         creationComplete="onTreeCreated(event)"/>
```

This will keep your entire tree open.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually fairly easy to do. You just have to make sure that the Component is bound to its dataProvider, rather than just referencing it. So, in mxml, that's curly brace syntax for assigning the dataProvider. Also, the DP has to be [Bindable].

If you do this, any time you update (add nodes, remove, rename, whatever) your data provider, it will be automagically updated in your control. No manual invalidating or updating required.

If you need an actual code example, let me know.

Comment: And, state is retained, obviously, because you are not replacing the dataProvider, just altering.

Answer (score 1):

For a Project with BlazeDS I had to work with updating and reloading Tree component data without breaking the User Experience (all nodes closed when data reloaded).
Instead of keeping tabs on “which node was opened before?” and “what was the scroll-position?” I found a way to inject the new state of the Tree component data into the existing data provider.

[Read the article here if you are interested](http://flashworks.wordpress.com/2010/08/29/blazeds-and-smooth-data-injection-dynamically-refreshing-a-flex-tree-view-data-provider/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this automatically (although i've never had to use the tree control).  I would think your best bet would be to extend the tree control and handle the recording of state yourself.

For instance I would possibly override the data property so that you could run a state checking function before you set a new data object on the component. Looking at the help there are methods

```
isItemOpen(item:Object):Boolean,
```

and

```
expandItem(item:Object, open:Boolean, animate:Boolean = false, dispatchEvent:Boolean = false, cause:Event = null):void
```

You need to recursively run through each node and check if it's open and storing the state for that node. Then when it has redrawn with the new data provider, recursively run through the new nodes and check to see if any of them were previously open, and if they were, expand them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the IUID interface on your data objects that represent your nodes.  The UID is a unique identifier that is usually just built off the data in the object, but sometimes it is more accurate to override this and make it some GUID that is persistent between data provider refreshes.  So the above will work when using a new dataprovider if the UIDs match.

Hope that made sense.

Answer (score 0):

Inferis's answer involving storing the openItems, and then setting them again after the data provider is updated, combined with implementing the IUID interface on the objects in the dataprovider array collection worked for me.

More info on IUID : http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=about_dataproviders_8.html

Answer (score 0):

In order the following snippet

```
var openItems:Object = tree.openItems;
tree.dataProvider = myNewDataProvider;
tree.openItems = openItems;
tree.validateNow();
```

or

```
callLater(keepOpenStateItems);

private function keepOpenStateItems():void {
    tree.openItems = openTreeItems; 
}
```

to work you must follow mattbilson and Michelle advice. They are absolutely right.

Just implemented the IUID of the object that is contained in the tree dataprovider and voila!
The collection refresh keeps the tree really at the state of where it was before.